# Deploying code to server - Questions

Tags: .net, windows-server, tfs

Hello Stack Exchange community, I have some questions that I need you guys to help me with, I will begin describing:

So, I am a .Net programmer and the Application that I am developing is based in MVC with some webforms(Some old stuff) and we have a Developing environment, a quality environment and finally, after quality it goes to production. We have Team Foundation Server as a source code management, the server that this is being hosted is in a Windows Server 2008 with a IIS version 7.

I think that's enough detail to explain my needs for information, now my problem:

When my team wants to deploy a Production or Quality release to the respective servers, we build and publish the respective solutions and copy/paste from our computer to the Windows Server Website Folder, which has led us to many problems.
This is not the right way of working, I know that, so I am asking you guys, any Software ranging from Open Source to Payable software to automate this work and what's the best way of doing a deploy of our code to the server?(The good practises) and of course, the software to do it.

Sorry for the long text and I hope that I got everything clear for you guys, if you need anymore info, please, ask me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terms you are looking for are called Continuous Integration and Continuous Deployment.

Continuous Integration (CI) can be as simple as an automated build server, with Continuous Deployment (CD) responsible for taking the build artifacts and publishing them in a repeatable way.

Where I work we use Azure DevOps or TeamCity as or CI tool chain, but there are ton of other great tools like Bamboo, Maven and TravisCI. We also use Octopus Deploy as our CD tool chain, but once again there are a ton of fantastic products available.

Hope this helps you start your DevOps journey.